# App Permission and Force stop

Tags: sms, permissions, privacy

Hello everybody :) I would be very grateful if you could answer my questions.

1- If the app has as a permission : Read and send text messages (SMS or MMS). Does it include  whatsapp and viber messages ?

2 - If I force stop an app, does it mean that the app's permissions are also disabled ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

1. SMS and MMS are general, system wide messages available through the Android API. Messages by any third-party app are independent from that and cannot be retrieved without reading the original database files containing those messages. (Which basically means it involves a rooted device/root permissions)
2. If you force close an app it is shut down and doesn't run. It does not remove any permissions what also means that another app may launch that app and that app may read your messages then.

Apps that don't run are not doing anything but the permissions persist. Using an application that is able to manage those permissions can *revoke* those permissions permanently.

Comment: I truly thank you for taking the time that you did to give me clear answers :D